# How to specify type of record constructor in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Say I have two distinct types with the same records:

```
type x = { a : int };;
type y = { a : int };;
```

Now `{ a = 5 }` will make a type `y` datum. Is there any way to force it to make a type `x` datum now?

I am aware that it is possible to wrap each type in a module but I'd like to avoid dealing with modules at this stage. Is there something like `{ a = 5 } : x` that would work?

Comment: It depends on your OCaml version. Also, if your two types are exactly the same, why not declare them once and then export them as different outside the module?

Comment: @PatJ Well, the simple answer is that I'm not at the level of OCaml proficiency where I'm dealing with modules yet ;) Really, I plan to avoid record sets with the same field names; it's just reassuring that there is a way to specify the type if that happens.

Comment: It's nice to know that people think about those subtleties before going deep into the language. I think you'll enjoy a lot the module system when you start learning it though. Happy hacking!

Answer (score 2):

Heh, I tried `{ a = 5 } : x` first and it didn't work, but just before posting I thought I'd try `({ a = 5 } : x)` and apparently that works.

Comment: Yes, the syntax of type indications can be quite tricky and often require parens.