How can I force a record literal to have a type in OCaml?
I have some record types with overlapping fields. This causes a type mismatch:
type apple =
  {
    price : int
  }

type banana =
  {
    price : int
  }

Is it possible to force the type of a record literal to be one or the other?
(Hypothetical syntax)
{
  apple.price = 123
}

{
  banana.price = 123
}


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935008/how-to-specify-type-of-record-constructor-in-ocaml ({price = 123} : apple)

Are you sure this shouldn't be something like the following? type fruit_species = Apple | Banana type fruit = { price : int; t : fruit_type }
